# ios default orientation with autorotation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation, autorotate

I'm developing an app which has 100 UIViewController almost. The app always run in portrait. But now, I want to allow rotate the app, buy only two screen (2  UIViewController).

So, in General settings, then in Deployment info, I mark:

```
Device Orientation -> Portrait
Device Orientation -> LandscapeLeft
Device Orientation -> LandscapeRight
```

And now, for example

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate return YES by default.

How avoid to override this method in every UIViewController? Which is the best solution? For me, its very difficult create a UIViewController superclass for all my UIViewController because some extends from TableViewController, another from UIViewController, another from...

Is there anyway to mark shouldautorate NO by default, supportedInterfaceOrientations only Portrait by default? And then, in a UIViewController that I want to rotate, override shouldautorotate, supported... I desire this option for maintenance of the project. No worry about a new UIViewController overrides this methods for no rotate or a new UIVC extends for a UIVC superclass that overrides this methods etc. Just, UIVC that I want rotate override the methods, otherwise you don't do anything.

Thanks, I hope you understand my question.

Comment: I think you can control it using appdelegate's application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method. By default return portrait and only for the specific VC's return all the orientation you want to support.

Comment: NO supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow is for another use. Is a mask for the values returned by the VC

Comment: I think you need to return the mask that the VC's need to use. So it should be UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait by default for portrait and for other VC's masked OR's like UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

Comment: But when you return back from a landscape view to a portrait view, this still in landscape

Comment: Call `attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` on the VC